# `Flask run` works perfectly, (FLASK_APP=main.py) but 'python main.py' produces errors

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

When I type `Flask run` to run my application, everything runs as expected. Dotenv sets `FLASK_APP=zigweb/main.py`. However, if I go to `zigweb` folder and type `python main.py` I get import errors. I'm developing in pycharm, I've separated out my project into a server, a telegram bot, and a flask app so I can dockerise.

Results of `flask run`

```
 * Serving Flask app "zigweb/main.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 264-034-887
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Results of `python main.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .app import app, db, signal_saved
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.app'; '__main__' is not a package
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from .app import app, db, signal_saved
from .app.models import User, Signal
from .app.functions import btc_to_satoshi
import pickle
from .pricedata import start_price_check
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Signal': Signal}


@app.context_processor
def satoshis():
    return dict(satoshis=btc_to_satoshi)


def some_func(signal):
    query = Signal.query.all()
    with open('.\\zigweb\signals.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(query, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        app.logger.info(f'Pickled object to {f}')


signal_saved.connect(some_func)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    start_price_check()
```

Project structure:

```
zigbot
  nginx
  zigbot (not flask)
      app
         scripts.py
      main.py
  zigweb (flask)
      app
        models.py
        __init__.py
        etc
      main.py
      some-other-scripts.py
```

If I change main.py to address the import errors, I don't understand how it then works with `flask run` if it fails with `python main.py`. Anyway, if I address the import errors by removing the '.' from `.app` Pycharm then red-underlines those imports, but it nearly runs.

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
C:\Users\phill\Anaconda3\envs\zigbot\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\zigbot\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

UPDATE 2
If I turn OFF debug, the server runs correctly by running `python main.py` but it produces the ABOVE error if debug is set to 1.

Comment: The directory 'C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\zigbot\' does not contain main.py. should it be 'C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\zigbot\zigweb\main.py' ?

Comment: It should, but I was running the script from the correct location - I was in the folder you mentioned 'C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\zigbot\zigweb\main.py and it still gave the above error.

Comment: where is your .env file and have you set 
'basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))' and 
'load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, '.env'))'